How to stop websites from tracking a user's mouse activity?
Websites can track users' mouse activity such as clicks, movement, scrolling. This can be used to infer some demographic characteristics such as age and gender (see "https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3406522.3446011" for more information). Are there ways to check if one's mouse activity can be tracked and are there some protections one can use to stop websites from getting this information? I am aware that disabling javascript will likely solve the problem, but it will also break the vast majority of websites so it's not feasible. Maybe some tracker blocking browser extension could help?
ETA: I asked the question from a user's perspective.

Some websites will use this as an anti-bot mechanism.

There’s no magic bullet for completely stopping mouse tracking since tracking is often integrated into how pages render. Even if you replaced the mouse with eye-tracking cameras, the privacy concerns would be even worse.
One option is designing your site to work with mouse-less browsers like Lynx, but that limits users to keyboard-only navigation, which still indirectly tracks pointer movement.
Ultimately, it’s up to the user to protect themselves. They can use extensions like uBlock Origin or Privacy Badger to block tracking scripts that monitor mouse activity. Browsers like Brave or Firefox with enhanced privacy settings offer anti-fingerprinting features that help reduce tracking. NoScript or similar tools let users selectively block scripts without fully disabling JavaScript. Alternatively, using virtual machines or sandboxed browsers can isolate tracking.

When I asked the question, I did so from a user's perspective. Regarding the privacy extensions, I have both of them installed in Brave browser. i tested if mouse tracking is possible on clickclickclick.click and deviceinfo.me and it was possible on both, unfortunately. Also how can a virtual machine defend against mouse tracking?

Great, we reached the same conclusion—tracking can still occur even with privacy extensions. Virtual machines mostly isolate tracking rather than block it directly. Unfortunately, mouse tracking is deeply tied to web functionality. You can try tweaking anti-fingerprinting settings or relying more on keyboard navigation, but full prevention is difficult while keeping current websites usable.
